# Spring application does not see files with properties extension (except application.properties)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, thymeleaf

I'm developing a Spring Boot web application that needs to get some numerical data from a **homepage.properties** file.

The thymeleaf template view however does not render any properties from files other than **application.properties** even if the .properties files are located inside the very same folder.

> src > main > resources > application.properties (gets properties successfully)
>
> src > main > resources > homepage.properties (does not get properties)

Here's a simple usage:

**application.properties**

```
working.hours=650
```

**homepage.properties**

```
test.hours=30
```

**index.html**

```
<h1 class="lan_fun_value mb-1" th:text="${@environment.getProperty('working.hours)}"></h1> //renders 650
<h1 class="lan_fun_value mb-1" th:text="${@environment.getProperty('test.hours)}"></h1> //renders nothing
```

Any ideas what could the problem be?

Comment: Why do you believe it *would* read the `homepage.properties` file? Did you tell Spring to load that file? Perhaps you should **read the documentation** describing how the environment properties are assigned: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config. --- #14 describes that `application.properties` is loaded by default. #16 describes how you can cause `homepage.properties` to be loaded. Read also section 2.3. Application Property Files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@PropertySources` for loading multiple properties file. You can write below code, above the application class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("application.properties"),
        @PropertySource("homepage.properties")
})
public class Application{

}
```

You have to add single quote after `working.hours` and `test.hours`.

Comment: Totally forgot i had to register them first because the application.properties is by default. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can add it directly by `@PropertySource("homepage.properties")`

Or inject it diretly by `@Value`

```
@Value( "${test.hours=30}")
private String testHours;
```

Or if you're using xml with spring:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="application.properties, homepage.properties"/>
```

Or pass it as argument while you command run your app.